# Order of Value.CreateBatch

Tags: c#, cntk

Can someone please confirm or correct my understanding of the order of values when using `Value.CreateBatch` instead of `MinibatchSource`?

Assuming the CTF equivalent is:

```
|x 1 2 3
|x 4 5 6
|x 7 8 9
```

Would a batch of size 3 become (a) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 or (b) 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9?

My current perception is (a) however I'd greatly appreciate this being confirmed or corrected. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, a) is the correct answer. In each line x is the name of the input data followed by the input data itself.

It is implicated in this tutorial for CNTK: https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/CNTK_103C_MNIST_MultiLayerPerceptron.html#Data-reading
and I also can tell it from my experience.